# Find File Directory By Searching Through Hard Drive

Tags: c++, file, search, directory, find

So I am trying to search through a specific hard drive (for example, C:) to find a file (like "HxD.exe"), and I am trying to get the specific directory to that file to launch with `CreateProcess()`. I know that this question has been answered before, but I have tried all those methods and none of them have worked for me (well, one worked but the type of string it gave me couldn't be converted to what `CreateProcess()` was looking for without losing data). Perhaps I am just doing it wrong? Anyways, if anyone knows anything that would work, if you would please tell me that would be great. I only need it to work for windows. 
Code for `FindFirstFile()`

```
LPWIN32_FIND_DATA fd = 0;
    HANDLE findFile = 0;

    do
    {
        findFile = FindFirstFile((LPCWSTR)"HxD.exe", fd);

        if (fd == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "ERROR " << GetLastError();
            // prints "ERROR 2"
        }

    } while (FindNextFile(findFile, fd));

    CloseHandle(findFile);
```

PS: Sorry if this is a very easy fix, I quickly whipped up some code at midnight because I deleted it all, and I don't have time to look it up b/c I am about to pass out lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You are using `FindFirstFile()` all wrong.

- `(LPCWSTR)"HxD.exe"` is an invalid type cast. You are casting a `const char[]` to a `const wchar_t*`. To make a proper wide string literal, you need to use `L"HxD.exe"` instead (or `TEXT("HxD.exe")` since you are using the `TCHAR` version of the API).
- You are passing in a NULL `WIN32_FIND_DATA*` pointer. `FindFirstFile()` (and `FindNextFile()`) expects a pointer to a pre-allocated `WIN32_FIND_DATA` instance, but you are not allocating anything.
- You are checking for a `FindFirstFile()` failure incorrectly. The *return value* will be `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` if the function fails. You are not checking for that condition.
- Lastly, you are asking `FindFirstFile()` to find `HxD.exe` only in the calling thread's current working directory. And you are not stopping your loop if the file is actually found. In fact, when searching for a specific filename, `FindFirstFile()` will either find it or not, and `FindNextFile()` will always return FALSE afterwards since there can only be 1 file in a given folder with the name being searched for. So your loop   becomes useless.

To search a whole partition correctly, you need to ask the API to search for the `*` wildcard instead, and then call the API in a recursive loop for each subdirectory that is found, checking the returned `WIN32_FIND_DATA` for non-subdirectories for the filename you are interested in.

With that said, try something more like this:

```c
#include <Shlwapi.h>

bool findFile(LPCWSTR path, LPCWSTR fileName, LPWSTR fullPath)
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATAW fd = {};
    DWORD dwError;

    WCHAR str[MAX_PATH] = {};
    PathCombineW(str, path, L"*");

    HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFileW(str, &fd);
    if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        dwError = GetLastError();
        if (dwError != ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) 
            std::cout << "ERROR " << dwError;
        return false;
    }

    do
    {
        if (fd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
        {
            if ((lstrcmpW(fd.cFileName, L".") != 0) &&
                (lstrcmpW(fd.cFileName, L"..") != 0))
            {
                PathCombineW(str, path, fd.cFileName);
                if (findFile(str, fileName, fullPath))
                {
                    CloseHandle(hFind);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if ((lstrcmpiW(fd.cFileName, fileName) == 0) ||
                (lstrcmpiW(fd.cAlternateFileName, fileName) == 0))
            {
                if (fullPath)
                    PathCombineW(fullPath, path, fd.cFileName);

                CloseHandle(hFind);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    while (FindNextFileW(hFind, &fd));

    dwError = GetLastError();
    if (dwError != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES) 
        std::cout << "ERROR " << dwError;

    CloseHandle(hFind);
    return false;
}
```

```c
WCHAR fullPath[MAX_PATH] = {};
if (findFile(L"C:\\", L"HxD.exe", fullPath))
{
    // use fullPath as needed...
}
```

To search an entire hard drive with multiple partitions, you can use [`GetLogicalDriveStrings()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getlogicaldrivestringsw):

```c
WCHAR drives[256] = {};
if (GetLogicalDriveStringsW(256, drives))
{
    WCHAR fullPath[MAX_PATH] = {};

    LPWSTR drive = drives;
    while (*drive)
    {
        if (findFile(drive, L"HxD.exe", fullPath))
        {
            // use fullPath as needed...
            break;
        }
        drive += (lstrlenW(drive)+1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `C++` compiler that support `C++17` version, you can make use of the `filesystem` functions. And if you don't  have access to C++17 version may be you can try `Boost` library.

You can try the `recursive_directory_iterator` function to iterate the subdirectories and files recursively and check if file that you are looking for exists.

```cpp
for(auto& p: fs::recursive_directory_iterator("C:/"))
        std::cout << p.path() << '\n'
```

**Rerferences:**

[std::filesystem](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator)

[boost filesystem](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#Class-recursive_directory_iterator)

Comment: While this is useful information, it doesn't actually address the OP's problem at all.

Comment: I agree. I thought may be I can convince @jacob to ignore the windows api approach to something better. :)

Comment: The OP is struggling to wrap their head around character encoding. If you want to help, make sure you are using the sane alternative on Windows (`L"C:&"` and `std::wcout`).